# sorting error :"already exist"

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, shutil

This code was suppose tu sort my desktop , path =/Users/nicolas/Desktop/prova/
and it works properly if the destination folder doesnt exist and the program create it , 
else  if there is already a folder with the same name  it give an error when he tries to move the files and it says

complete output:

.DS_Store
nltks
png
Scherm.png
Schermata 2018-03-28 alle 11.07.13.png
DS_Store
nltks
png
png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicolas/Desktop/tts/work in progress/sorting machine.py", line 16, in 
    shutil.move(path+names[x],path+currentexp)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 292, in move
    raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst
shutil.Error: Destination path '/Users/nicolas/Desktop/prova/png/Scherm.png' already exists
iMac:w

but i ve not any file in it with the ds_store estension and the "nltk" is just a folder that shouldnt move .

program

```
import os
import shutil

path = "/Users/nicolas/Desktop/prova/"
names  = os.listdir(path)
for x in range (0,len(names)):
    print names[x]
for x in range (0,len(names)):
    exp = names[x].split(".")
    currentexp = exp[-1]
    print (currentexp)
    if os.path.exists(path+currentexp):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, names[x]), os.path.join(path,currentexp))
    else:
        os.makedirs(path+currentexp)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, names[x]), os.path.join(path,currentexp))
 #   if names[x] not in os.path.exists(path+currentexp):
 #       shutil.move(path+names[x],path+curentexp)
```

thanks for the help

Comment: If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics: if the image exists in the target dir, `shutil.move` will fail. You have to delete it first.

Comment: it's not related to sorting.

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

> If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics

To sum it up, if the image exists in the target dir, and both source & target dirs are on the same filesystem, `shutil.move` can use `os.rename`, and `os.rename` fails because you cannot rename an object with the name of an already existing one. You have to delete the target first.

Here's how I'd rewrite it:

```
target_dir = os.path.join(path,currentexp)
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.makedirs(target_dir)

try:
    os.remove(os.path.join(target_dir, names[x]))
except OSError:
    pass  # cannot remove or doesn't exist, ignore

shutil.move(os.path.join(path, names[x]), target_dir)
```

this simpler code tries to delete the target file before performing `shutil.move`. Of course `os.remove` can fail, failure is trapped, then `shutil.move` fails because of another error, but that's beyond our scope

Comment: ine 18
    except OSError :
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax